# Generar respuestas aleatorias y entre esas la correcta

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
$numero = rand(1, 6); //Genero un número aleatorio del 1 al 6
$sql=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM typo WHERE id=$numero"); //busco en la base de datos ese número
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
$fuente=$row['fuente']; //recojo el dato correspondiente a ese número
$id_buena=$row['id']; //recojo el id que es el número en la base de datos
?>
```

Lo que hace la aplicación es mostrar el dato aleatorio que he cogido en pantalla. Y pregunta al usuario que adivine entre tres opciones cual es la que se está mostrando en pantalla.

Entonces intento generar tres opciones entre las cuales quiero que aparezca la correcta:

```
<ul>
<?php
$sql_f=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM typo WHERE id<>$numero ORDER BY rand(" . time() . " * " . time() . ") LIMIT 2");
while ($row_c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_f)){
    $fuente_c=$row_c['fuente'];
    $id=$row_c['id'];
        echo '<li><a href="'.$id.'">'.$fuente_c.'</a></li>';
}
echo '<li><a href="'.$id_buena.'">'.$fuente.'</a></li>';
?>
</ul>
```

El problema está en que la respuesta correcta siempre va a ser la tercera opción. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se mezclen las 3 opciones y entre ellas esté la correcta?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno lo que se me ha ocurrido es generar un número aleatorio de 1 a 3 y hacer un echo al número ramdom que ha salido. De esa forma se mezclarían las opciones

```
<?php
$sql_f=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM typo WHERE id<>$numero ORDER BY rand(" . time() . " * " . time() . ") LIMIT 2");
$contador=1;
$random_number=rand(1,3);
while ($row_c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_f)){
    if($random_number==$contador){
       echo '<li><a href="'.$id_buena.'">'.$fuente.'</a></li>';
    }else{
       $fuente_c=$row_c['fuente'];
       $id=$row_c['id'];
       echo '<li><a href="'.$id.'">'.$fuente_c.'</a></li>';
    }
    $contador++;
}
?>
```